# Updating existing software package with Advanced Installer

Tags: .net, windows-installer, updates, advanced-installer

I have created an Installation Package using [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com).

How can I implement following features

If I install a software, and then install a newer version of the same software A.msi,I want the older version to automatically get uninstalled and overwritten.

2.If the framework for eg framework 4.0 or 3.5 does not exist,it should give a message to user to download it from the right location.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Its the default configuration in all projects you create with Advanced Installer, of course as long as you increase your product version. The next article has more details about upgrades:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/upgrades.html

2) This is a standard prerequisite, which you can select from our list of predefined ones. Just select the version you want and Advanced Installer will handle the rest for you. More details about prerequisites here:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/prerequisites.html

Comment: But @BordanMitrache I added the framework prerequisite to the installer which i had set to framework 4.5.My System already has framework 4.5 installed,It still forces me to install framework 4.5.I want that if the framework is installed,it should skip the framework installation and proceed to the main installation.How is it to be done?

Comment: @Vivek send us the project file to support@advancedinstaller.com and also please mention on what OS you are testing it. I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @BordganMitrache sorry for duplicating the question.Actually I wanted to try it out by myself.Eg suppose your system already has .net framework 4.5 and the installer that I created asks you again to install the framework.
As your system already has .net 4.5 ,the installer should automatically skip the .net framework installation without forcing you to install the package again.

I hope my doubt is clear

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but there was a small configuration problem in our default prerequisite for .Net 4.5 with older versions of AI, this is why I recommended to send us the project by email. Basically the problem was the installer still asked you to install the prerequisite on Windows 8 or 8.1 (where it is installed by default.)   You need to make sure the launch condition from Setup Files tab of your prerequisite do not have this OS-es selected.